# Is there a Lagrangian for Super-Gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, action, supergravity

Einsteins field equations can be derived from the Einstein-Hilbert action which only involves the scalar curvature $R$ of the spacetime manifold. This is simply

$$S = \int_M R.$$

The volume form or measure here is left implicit as is quite common when the integral is written over a manifold.

Is there a similar Lagrangian for [super-gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity) and does it similarly involve a kind of scalar curvature suitably interpreted?

Comment: These might be useful https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2051

Comment: ... *which* supergravity?

Comment: @Nihar Karve: Take your pick.

Comment: @MoziburUllah well the answer can be yes, and the $D$-dimensional Ricci scalar is usually present, along with other field strength terms, etc.

Comment: (Also your action really should include the volume measure $\sqrt{-g} d^4x$)

Comment: @Eletie: it's quite common in both mathematics and mathematical physics to omit the the volume form or measure, the presence of this being understood when integrating over a manifold.

Comment: @MoziburUllah This isn't very common in the context of supergravity or GR, at least in physics texts, due to the metric determinant often being used explicitly and the dimension of the theory not being clear (e.g. compactifications from $D \rightarrow d$).

Comment: @Eletie: Ackowledged. I've added a comment in the post to point this out. Personally, I prefer it as it simplifies equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the simple case of $\mathcal{N}=1$ on-shell supergravity in 4 dimensions with no matter content. The full action is made up of the Einstein-Hilbert term and the [Rarita-Schwinger action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarita%E2%80%93Schwinger_equation) for the gravitino, with
$$
S_{EH}=\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int\mathrm d^4 x\det e\ e^\mu_ae^\nu_bR^{ab}_{\mu\nu}(\omega)
$$
where $R_{\mu\nu}^{ab}$ is the field strength of the spin connection $\omega_\mu^{ab}$ and $\det e$ takes the place of the volume element.

Since this SUGRA theory can formally be defined as a gauge theory with gauge group $\text{SO}(1, d-1)$, the commutator of the supercovariant derivatives defines the Riemann tensor above:
$$
[D_\mu, D_\nu]=\frac14R_{\mu\nu}^{ab}\gamma_{ab}
$$

So $e^\mu_ae^\nu_bR^{ab}_{\mu\nu}(\omega)$ *is* essentially the Ricci scalar in the spin-connection-vielbien formalism. The spin connection here is actually a function of the vielbien, and on introducing supersymmetry, also of the fermionic fields (which you can see when you find the EOM for $\omega$ in the first-order formalism).

The presence of the scalar curvature in the action is a feature of all supergravity theories. There are of course Lagrangian descriptions for things like type IIA SUGRA as well, obtained as the low-energy effective action of type IIA string theory:
$$
S = \frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int\mathrm d^{10}x\sqrt{-g}e^{-2\phi}\left(R+4\partial_\mu\Phi\partial^\mu\Phi-\frac1{12}|H_3|^2\right)-\frac{1}{4\kappa^2}\int\mathrm d^{10}x\sqrt{-g}\left(|F_2|^2+|\tilde F_4|^2\right)-\frac{1}{4\kappa^2}\int\mathrm d^{10}x\sqrt{-g}\ B_2\wedge F_4\wedge F_4
$$
with the three terms corresponding respectively to the bosonic part, the RR part and the Chern-Simons part. You can remove the ugly $e^{-2\phi}$ in the bosonic action by going to the Einstein frame through a conformal rescaling, whereupon you pick up the familiar Einstein-Hilbert term $\int\mathrm d^n x \sqrt{-g} R$.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks a lot simpler and clearer than the equations I was just looking at.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why only write down the bosonic part of the action?

Comment: @Andrew for the simple reason that I couldn't be bothered to write the RR-terms. However, I will gladly oblige.